# Using PNG as background image -- can't see it in design view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, svg, png

I have a background I created on Sketch which I want to use as the UI for the app, where I'll just put in invisible buttons where they are on the .png file.

I have the file in my drawable, and an imageview in the app with its height and width set as match_parent. Using the glide library, I loaded the image which is like 3.7MB, into the imageview, and this works, when I'm using the app on my device or emulator. The problem is, I cannot see the .png as the background when I try to put the buttons on top of the .png, since it only loads once the app starts. I've read that you could try to convert to SVG, however, when I tried this, nothing shows up.

Is there any way where I could load the image as the background another way? Or is there another way I could make a UI, or is there a way I can just load the .png?

[image: login_activity - text]

[image: llogin_activity - design]

[image: LoginActivity Class]

Comment: Please don't include code as images.  Include code as code.  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio has the nifty `tools` namespace.

If you add

```
tools:src="@drawable/loginscreen"
```

to your ImageView in XML, the design view will show the image, but the attribute will be ignored during compile time and won't be present in the APK itself.

`tools:` also works for most XML attributes.

You may need to import the `tools` namespace (click the red `tools` text and hit Alt+Enter).

Comment: I can't believe that was all it needed, thanks babe. So when I run the app on my phone, it will be ignored right?